# Join results from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have two MySQL tables from which i can't get joined results.

The first one is just a list of companies and their names:

```
companies:
____________________________
companyid  |  companyname  |
1               comp1
2               comp2
```

The second one is the list of user roles:

```
roles:
_____________________________________________________
roleid  |  uid  | role  |  companyid  |  suspended  |
1           1     dir           1           0
2           1     manag         2           0
```

I want to get a result that would look like:

```
_______________________
companyname  |  role  |
comp1           dir
comp2           manag
```

My query below returns nothing...

```
SELECT companies.companyid, roles.role FROM companies INNER JOIN roles ON roles.companyid=companies.companyname where (uid = 1 and suspended = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you joining condition.

Try this,

```
select a.companyname,b.role from companies a, roles b
    where a.companyid=b.companyid and
    (b.uid = 1 and
    b.suspended <> 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, it returns nothing though :(

Comment: it will not return anything based on the data given here. change the last condition b.supended <> 0 to b.suspended = 0

Comment: *facepalm.jpg* gosh, im so stupid, i really meant that suspended must be equal to zero.

Comment: not at all, sometimes a little mistake destroy our whole day... :P

Comment: We tend to discourage archaic join syntax around here. The '90s were cool, but they're so over.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining roles.companyid=companies.companyname which is incorrect since companyname is a string, not an integer.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT companies.companyid, roles.role FROM companies INNER JOIN roles ON roles.companyid=companies.companyid where (uid = 1 and suspended <> 0);
```

Comment: Please note you are missing `);` at the end of the line. The query returns null :(

Comment: Still nothing, even though, i made suspended=0 instead suspended <>0, anyway, the other solutions works fine. Thank you anyway